# (Android) Two-dimensional array and Spinner

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, spinner

I have a (simple) two-dimensional array. What I am trying to do is populate spinner with data from that array.

```
String ap1[][] = new String[5][2];
ap1[0][0]="First item";
ap1[0][1]="1";
ap1[1][0]="Second item";
ap1[1][1]="2";
//etc. etc. etc.

Spinner apSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ap_spinner);
```

Now the spinner should get populated with first elements from each array entry (e.g. *"First item", "Second item",...*) and the second item should be read after a selection has been made and used in later calculations.

I've tried with following code, but got some weird text like  *LJava.Lang.String;@...*

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ap1);
apSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Any clues on my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a dimension to the array makes your life harder. If you goal of your 2nd dimension is to

> should be read after a selection has been made and used in later

You can achieve/get the same number in `position+1` . Depending one when/how you will use it.

You also have to remember, what you see in your list ([Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29)):

> To use something other than TextViews for the array display, for
>   instance, ImageViews, or to have some of data besides toString()
>   results fill the views, override getView(int, View, ViewGroup) to
>   return the type of view you want.

So you will see `String[].toString()` , since its the 2nd dimension. Hence you see `classname@hashcode`

Comment: @MarsMan If you have found this helpful and solved the problem, you can mark this as correct answer by check the green mark on the left of the answer.

Comment: I agree about making life harder :). The number in 2nd position isn't as simple as in given example code. It is even not incrementing in equal steps...

Comment: In this case. You should make a custom class. The biggest problem your facing is in Arrays you cannot override the toString() method(as explained in last sentence.) You can make ArrayList<CustomClass> with an Overrided toString() method, and which holds your 2nd postion number.